# Make NodeJS Promise resolution to wait for all processing to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using util.promisify to convert Gmail API calls to promises.

```
async function listHistory(id, nextId, auth) {
  logger.info("Pulling all changes after historyId: " + id);

  let gmail = google.gmail('v1');

  let list = util.promisify(gmail.users.history.list);

  return list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    startHistoryId: id
  }).then(function(response) {

    if(typeof response !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof response !== "undefined") {
            if(typeof response.data === "object") {
                if(typeof response.data.history === "object") {
                    response.data.history.forEach(function(history) {
                        if(typeof history.messages === "object") {
                          history.messages.forEach(function(message) {
                            getMessage(message.id, auth); // >>> This is a network call
                          });
                        }
                    });
                }         
            }
        }
    }

  }).catch(exception => {
    logger.info("Pulling changes for historyId: " + id + " returned error: " + exception);
  });
}
```

Here is the code that calls above promise returning function

```
let promise = await googleCloudModules.listHistory(currentHistoryId, newHistoryId, oauth2Client).then(response => {
  console.log("DONE!");
}).catch(exception => {
  console.log(exception);
});
```

The promise is resolved even before all the processing is finished i.e. the forEach loop network calls. Can I make it resolve only after all network calls in foreach loop are finished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) a (re)read-through. What should your async function return? Because right now it's not returning a normal Promise, you're already seemingly handing the `list()` promise inside the function by giving it a `.then.catch`, so what do you actually need it to return?

Comment: also note that your nested `if` have some duplication, and can also be simplified at several steps. E.g. `if (response  && response.data && response.data.history) { let h = response.data.history; h.forEach(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all and map all the network calls in an array. Changing a little of your code as an example

```
async function listHistory(id, nextId, auth) {
    logger.info("Pulling all changes after historyId: " + id);

    let gmail = google.gmail('v1');

    let list = util.promisify(gmail.users.history.list);

    //you can await the list.
    try {
        const response = await list({
            auth: auth,
            userId: 'me',
            startHistoryId: id
        })
        const getMessagePromiseArray = [];
        if (response && response.data && Array.isArray(response.data.history)) {
            response.data.history.forEach(function (history) {
                if (Array.isArray(history.messages)) {
                    history.messages.forEach(function (message) {
                        getMessagePromiseArray.push(getMessage(message.id, auth)); // >>> This is a network call
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return Promise.all(getMessagePromiseArray);
    } catch (exception) {
        logger.info("Pulling changes for historyId: " + id + " returned error: " + exception);
    };
}
```